# open gallery from sdcard in android

Tags: android

I am trying to open gallery from sdcard.But it shows pictures from gallery but not the sdcard. I take photo and it save/mnt/sdcard/Pictures/Gallery and it didnt show anything.

Open Gallery code

if (id == R.id.open_gallery) 
{

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Uri.parse("content://media/internal/images/media"));      
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

}

Comment: `it save/mnt/sdcard/Pictures/Gallery and it didnt show anything.`. Switch your device off and on again. But are they really saved there? Dont think so. Tell the exact full path in `fileName` please.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Content Resolver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html) and use Media Store class, you will get all images from external media inside a cursor.

```
MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
```

Check the this [url](http://www.coderanch.com/t/443531/Android/Mobile/display-Images-stored-sdcard)

Comment: Cursor cc = this.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, null, null, null,null);
         startManagingCursor(cc);

Comment: It does not show anything and I want to open gallery from sdcard and pick one

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to open gallery from sdcard.

There is no requirement that any Android device have this capability. A device does not need to have *any* sort of "gallery", let alone one controllable in this fashion.

> I take photo and it save/mnt/sdcard/Pictures/Gallery

No, you do not. For one, not every device has such a location.

> Take photo

This has nothing to do with [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html). This is saving images on [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html).

> Open Gallery code

There is no requirement that there be an app with an activity that supports that `Intent`. Even if there is, you are not passing the location that you used when you saved the image. `content://media/internal/images/media` is not `new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), APP_TAG)`.

Use [the instructions from the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36554370/115145) and build your own image-browsing capability into your app.